# grub-install: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition

Tags: boot, grub2

I have an installation of Ubuntu 15.04 that has been working fine for some weeks. Today, my box locked up to the point I had to power it off in order to clear the error. When I did so, it stopped booting.

When booting, it comes up and displays a cursor and nothing else.

I tried following the advice here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/reinstall-grub-ubuntu-wont-boot/ but when I do so, it gives me this error:

```
Installing for i386-pc  platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible. GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists. However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

Any advice as to what to try next?

Comment: If you have a UEFI system it has two totally different ways to boot, UEFI and CSM. CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode  If you boot in UEFI mode drive must be gpt partitioned and has an ESP - efi  system partition. But you can boot in BIOS mode, but must install grub to the gpt's protective MBR and must have the bios_grub partition. You must have an UEFI system, and now are reinstalling grub in BIOS/Legacy/CSM mode without the bios_grub partition. If you want to convert to BIOS add the bios_grub partition. Or boot and reinstall grub in UEFI mode.

Comment: This situation has happened to me after upgrading a working Debian PC. I'm at a total loss as to whether it's fixable. There's no space for mysterious extra partitions, and I'm stumped as to why they'd suddenly be necessary.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Way too late to help you, but this might help someone else who, like me, landed on this page in search for a solution to this problem.
A small partition has to be created on the disk and marked as a code EF02  "BIOS boot partition". Somewhere I read it should be 200MB, I only had room for a 1007.0 KiB one and it worked just the same.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was getting this error on chroot and discovered my /boot partitions were just Linux and not BIOS.  grub-intall no longer reporting errors now.

Answer (score 3):

To solve the problem, I had to mark the first partition as "bios_grub" via [gparted](https://gparted.org/).
This partition can be used for nothing else afterwards! It does not hold the boot image, but only the boot manager.

Before:

```
$ grub-install /dev/sdb
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: error: embedding is not possible, but this is required for cross-disk install.
```

After:

```
$ grub-install /dev/sdb
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

Comment: Were you able to boot your OS after that? I was able to get grub installed the same way you show it there, but my computer is still not able to boot the OS

Comment: yes, it did work after that.

Comment: For me, VirtualBox crashes in the boot when doing this (Guru Meditation). Have not tested on real hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also late posting but for others' benefit, I just encountered the same error on a Ubuntu Server 18.04 machine configured for EFI boot from a GPT disk.

Oversimplifying, two boot modes exist (BIOS and EFI) and two disk partition schemes exist (MBR and GPT).  BIOS/MBR are from the "old" days, EFI/GPT are current.  GRUB installs in (a) the boot sector of a MBR-formatted disk; (b) for BIOS-mode systems in a small (<1 MiB) unformatted "BIOS Boot Partiton" on a GPT-formatted disk; and (c) for EFI-mode systems in a ~512MiB vfat/FAT32-formatted EFI System Partition.

It looks as if the OP had a BIOS-mode system with a GPT disk.

My case was an EFI-mode system with a GPT disk but I was getting the same error.

The problem was that there also are two forms of GRUB, one for BIOS-mode systems (grub-pc)(i386-pc) and another for EFI-mode systems (grub-efi)(x86_64).  The former was installed and the latter, wasn't.  The giveaways were (a) the error was inappropriate because the system was booted in EFI mode to a GPT disk; and (b) grub-install insisted on a device specification (*e.g.*, /dev/sda)(and threw the above error when it got one) but doesn't take one when executed on an EFI-mode system.  The fix was simple once the problem was identified:

```
# apt install grub-efi
# update-grub
# grub-install
```

Hopefully, this will save someone else some time.