# Can't reinstall Grub from Live USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

The stroy were i've installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS then i installed Windows 10 on my laptop (dual boot). It was on UEFI mode installation.

So, when i restart my laptop, it boot into Windows 10. After that, i reinstall Grub from Ubuntu Live USB. But, it wasn't succeed

What i have done so far is :

**Terminal** :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run
> do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i
> done
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo chroot /mnt
root@ubuntu:/# grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

**Disk** :

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048  78125055  78123008  37.3G EFI System
/dev/sda2   78125056 488493055 410368000 195.7G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  488493056 506071039  17577984   8.4G Linux swap
/dev/sda4  506071040 506103807     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda5  506103808 976773119 470669312 224.4G Microsoft basic data
```

**EDIT**

It is too long to reply @oldfred comment with this text. So i put it here.

Hi @oldfred .. i've been confusing about Operating System Booting settings. I set booting mode on UEFI (Secure Boot), after that i installed Ubuntu. `During installation`, it said i did something wrong (not recommended way) after created partition and it must be use Legacy BIOS to make dual-boot possible in the future. So, i went to change the Boot's Settings mode to Legacy BIOS. After that i installed Ubuntu with succeed. Then i installed Windows (still on Legacy BIOS mode). It was succeed as well. Then i went to recover  GRUB to enable dual-boot. I followed this tutorial (https://www.linuxdeveloper.space/install-windows-after-linux/#repair-grub-efi). I reboot my laptop .. just end up with Windows appeared after booting.

Any idea why i can't reinstall grub ?

Comment: If you installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode, you need to always boot in UEFI mode. But if it asks for bios_grub that is BIOS boot and then you are installing the BIOS boot version of grub (grub-pc). Can you not use UEFI boot menu often f10 or f12 to boot Ubuntu? And in UEFI/BIOS set Ubuntu as first in boot order. Or change boot order with efibootmgr - https://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr

Comment: @karel .. it seems the same. I've tried to create bios-boot partition as it said on the answer. It wasn't work. Still, it displayed Windows 10 when my laptop boot.

Comment: @oldfred .. i've updated my question. i reply your question there because it is too long.

Comment: This warning is telling us what is the problem: `grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.` -- You have no partition with a `bios_grub` flag. See this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Comment: You have a mixed-mode (BIOS and EFI) installation, which is a recipe for frustration. See the [GRUB2 does not show Windows 8 option to boot into after Dual Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931094/grub2-does-not-show-windows-8-option-to-boot-into-after-dual-boot) duplicate. Although the phrasing and details are different, the solutions should work. The other marked alternate (grub-install: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition)[https://askubuntu.com/questions/671809/grub-install-this-gpt-partition-label-contains-no-bios-boot-partition) is not a good match for you.

Comment: What brand/model system? OP is confused by trying to reinstall grub in (wrong) BIOS mode which is not working to fix an issue of wanting Ubuntu as first or default boot. UEFI may be the one complaining as some brands only want to default allow "Windows Boot Manager" as UEFI boot.