# Ubuntu 20.04 boot error - Firmware bug; Hardaware error; ACPI does not cover the entire command/response buffer;

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, acpi

I get this error with some linux distros (I use ubuntu, but I checked and tested several others distros to see if the same problem occurred) when I click to try or when I install and boot (exept Ubuntu 20.04 it doesn't even boot)

I use Ubuntu but since I upgraded to the version 20.04 it's crashes when I boot, I don't know why.

I tried to install via USB, and I got the error below when booting Ubuntu via USB and at the end of the installation when I restarted to boot it now installed on my computer (Ubuntu 20.04 installs normally, it just doesn't boot).

The error:

```
[0.000000] [Firmware Bug] : Failed to parse event in TPM Final Events Log

[0.110504] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 6: ee20000000 40110a

[0.110507] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR fef1cbc0 MISC 43880018086

[0.110511] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:806e9 TIME 1587846870 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode ca

[0.110515] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 7: ee20000000 40110a

[0.110516] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR fef1ce40 MISC 7880018086

[0.110519] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:806e9 TIME 1587846870 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode ca

[0.469097] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug] : ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80

[0.469161] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80

[6.445359] usb 1-8: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -110

[6.445383] usb 1-8: can't read configurations, error -110

[22.189227] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[27.693351] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/al1, error -110

[33.581311] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/8, error -110

[38.957346] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/8, error -110

[49.917213] usb 1-8: device not accepting address 7, error -62

[49.917289] usb usb1-port8: unable to enumerate USB device /dev/sda6:clean, 207846/12500992 files, 2707452/50000128 blocks
```

> What happens:

- Ubuntu 20.04 in particular, when Installed does not boot, the screen flashes and it goes back to the boot screen.
- But other Ubuntu versions boot (I tested 18.04 and 19.10), showing the error above when booted and shutted down.
- Pop OS doesn't install and returns me a log file with the problem:

...blablabla everything behind is OK...

```
[INFO distinst:src/installer/state.rs:33] starting configuring bootloader step

[INFO distinst:src/installer/steps/bootloader.rs:35] /dev/sda: installing bootloader for Bios

[INFO distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:108] running "chroot" "/tmp/distinst.7LIcsjMhokfz" "grub-install" "--recheck" "--target=i386-pc" "/dev/sda"

[WARN distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:98] Installing for i386-pc platform.

[WARN distinst:crates/chroot/src/command.rs:98] grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.

[ERROR distinst:src/installer/state.rs:37] configuring bootloader error: command failed with exit status: exit code: 1

[ERROR distinst:src/installer/mod.rs:298] errored while installing system: command failed with exit status: exit code: 1

[INFO distinst:ffi/src/installer.rs:188] Install error: command failed with exit status: exit code: 1*
```

(I installed PoP OS to see if the problem occured, but it doesn't even install. I don't know if this has to do with what's going on with Ubuntu)

> What I already did:

- Download Ubuntu again...and again
- Reinstall Ubuntu several times
- Update BIOS
- Reset BIOS
- I use dual boot with Windows 10, and about the Hardware error, I run a test with the supportassist tool from Dell (because my laptop is a Dell) to check the entire hardware on windows, and says that is everything ok (but I don't know if this is right).
- Reset my HD -> reinstall Windows -> insert bootable USB -> partitioned HD to dual boot with Ubuntu 20.04 -> Reboot -> Grub screen -> Click on Ubuntu 20.04 -> Screen flashes -> Reboot (it's not me that reboot) -> Grub screen -> Click on Windows -> And Windows boot

> Why only Ubuntu 20.04 does not boot?

Comment: Assuming that you've installed the latest BIOS for your machine, then it's probably a bug in the BIOS or TPM. In your BIOS, disable TPM, and disable Secure Boot, and see if it all starts to work. Report back.

Comment: It didn't work :(

Comment: Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: I managed to solve with this link https://dellwindowsreinstallationguide.com/ubuntu-20-04/. From what I've seen in previous research, may have to do with the way I formatted my HD!

Comment: Because when I formatted the HD to make a dual boot, I didn’t format it in whole, I formatted only a part in GPT, I don’t know if this has anything to do with it, but I’m going to do the memory test that you sent me heynnema, that message memory error is very strange!

Comment: Laying down a GPT partition table is for the whole disk. I reviewed the link that you gave, and with the exception of the MOK part, it looks like a pretty standard installation procedure that you should have been doing anyway. I suggested the memory test because of the MCE errors in your log. Report back.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**
Only info:
If Windows installed with "secure boot" (option in Bios) and Linux with "legacy boot" installed.
The system will boot only when you switch options to the one from which you installed the operating system.
I'm not saying it's a rule, but it does happen sometimes.

Check this.
[grub-install: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671809/grub-install-this-gpt-partition-label-contains-no-bios-boot-partition)

This is possible because I have often seen incompatible EFI partitions for various operating systems.
Another way is to have two hard drives and create your own EFI partition in GPT or create a disk in MBR format.
The disk boot order can be changed from BIOS, it will also change the booting system.
I advise you to read a little about GPT and MBR.
Linux support MBR and GPT (but GPT in diffrend degrees).
Windows only new GPT, so not will boot on MBR, even the installation probably won't work. But I'm not sure if this applies to every version of Windows and hardware. Because what I saw does not coincide with the opinions of my friend on the forum.

**Edit.**
About ACPI. This is another bug.
With this bug Linux should work.
However you can always report error https://bugzilla.kernel.org/describecomponents.cgi?product=ACPI

**Edit**
Can you show output of command from Ubuntu from live-usb ?

```
inxi -Fxz
```

**Edit**
Check this also

- https://www.reddit.com/r/tails/comments/hwv3zo/0000000_firmware_bug_failed_to_parse_event_in_tmp/

> Disable TPM (Trusted Platform Module) in your bios and you'll be fine.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module

**Edit**
You can test also https://www.dell.com/support/article/pl-pl/sln306327/manual-nomodeset-kernel-boot-line-option-for-linux-booting?lang=en